# How to stream audio and capture at the same time

Tags: bash, audio, streaming, sox, lame

I would like to save the mp3 that is being stream to the local file for archival purposes.

I'm using the following line in my bash script to stream audio from a USB audio device to my icecast server.

```
/usr/bin/sox -t ossdsp -s -r 44100 -c 2 /dev/dsp1 -t raw - | \
/usr/bin/lame -r -a -m mono -b 24 --cbr --resample 22500 --lowpass 4 - - 2> /tmp/status.lame | \
/usr/bin/ezstream -qvc ezstream-config.xml
```

This is running on a Raspberrypi running Rasbpian.

Answer (score 2):

So `sox` pipes to `lame` which pipes to `ezstream`? How about add in a `tee` somewhere to save a copy? I'm not super-familiar with the tools you're using, but `tee` can *"read from standard input and write to standard output and files"* so it could copy one of the pipes to a file.

Something like this might work, `tee` between lame & ezstream:

```
/usr/bin/sox -t ossdsp -s -r 44100 -c 2 /dev/dsp1 -t raw - | \
/usr/bin/lame -r -a -m mono -b 24 --cbr --resample 22500 --lowpass 4 - - 2> /tmp/status.lame \
| tee outputfile-lame | \
/usr/bin/ezstream -qvc ezstream-config.xml
```